# Can't make jQuery animation work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make the top div fade out when it is clicked, but I can't get it to work. Here is my code:

```
<script type = 'text/javascript' src = '../Javascript/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.js'></script>
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#topcontent').click (
        function() {
        $('#topcontent').fadeTo(300,0.0);
        }
    );
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = 'wrapper'>
        <div id = 'topcontent'>
        TOP<br />
        </div>
        <div id = 'bottomcontent'>
        BOTTOM
        </div>
        <div id = 'sub'>
        This site is still being created. Check back soon!
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Any ideas on why it's not working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot a closing parenthesis at the end of `$(document).ready(function(){});`.

Comment: Ah... dumb mistake on my part. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, we all make those small mistakes sometimes. You should look into getting a debugger, such as firebug, or using the developer tools in most browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You just have a syntax error

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#topcontent').click (
    function() {
        $('#topcontent').fadeTo(300,0.0);
    });
});
```